# hasNext returning wrong result

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

I want to check if the relation between two nodes exists or not. If exists I want to update the property else add new relation between specified nodes. A groovy script is used to read data from a CSV file and run the queries.

```
g.V().has('label_A','A').outE('to').inV().has('label_B','B').hasNext() ? g.V().has('label_A','A').outE('to').as('e').inV().has('label_B','B').select('e').property('created','existed') : g.V().has('label_A','A').as('fromV').V().has('label_B','B').as('toV').addE('to').from('fromV').to('toV').property('created','newAdded')
```

g.V().has('label_A','A').outE('to').inV().has('label_B','B').hasNext() is always returning false even if the relation exists between given two nodes when ran through groovy script.
The same command on the gremlin console returns the expected output. Hence new relations are created always.

Also tried the following query

```
g.V().hasLabel('label_A','A').as('v').V().has('label_B','B').coalesce(__.inE('to').where(outV().as('v')),addE('to').from('v').property('created','newAdded')).property('created','existed')
```

The above query doesn't work. No relations are added.

Comment: Couple of suggestions and questions:
1. You can replace outE('to').inV() with out('to') 
2. Are you storing label_A as a property or as a vertex label? If it is a vertex label, then your query might be incorrect. In case of vertex label, you can replace has('label_A','A') with hasLabel('A') (same for b)

Comment: label_A is not a vertex label. It is a property. As the label is reserved, I am using label_A. I am using outE('to').inV() because there may be many edges outing from A to B, C, etc. But I want to select an edge to label_B, not others

Answer (score 1):

From a pure Gremlin perspective I think you would prefer to write that traversal as:

```
g.V().has('label_A','A').
  outE('to').where(inV().has('label_B','B')).
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold().property('created','existed'),
           addE('to').
           from(V().has('label_A','A')).
           to(V().has('label_B','B')).
           property('created','newAdded'))
```

In this way it will execute in a single request/transaction rather than two separate operations. You can see it in action in the following Gremlin Console session with TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('label_A','A').iterate()
gremlin> g.addV().property('label_B','B').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has('label_A','A').
......1>   outE('to').where(inV().has('label_B','B')).
......2>   fold().
......3>   coalesce(unfold().property('created','existed'),
......4>            addE('to').
......5>            from(V().has('label_A','A')).
......6>            to(V().has('label_B','B')).
......7>            property('created','newAdded'))
==>e[4][0-to->2]
gremlin> g.E().elementMap()
==>[id:4,label:to,IN:[id:2,label:vertex],OUT:[id:0,label:vertex],created:newAdded]
gremlin> g.V().has('label_A','A').
......1>   outE('to').where(inV().has('label_B','B')).
......2>   fold().
......3>   coalesce(unfold().property('created','existed'),
......4>            addE('to').
......5>            from(V().has('label_A','A')).
......6>            to(V().has('label_B','B')).
......7>            property('created','newAdded'))
==>e[4][0-to->2]
gremlin> g.E().elementMap()
==>[id:4,label:to,IN:[id:2,label:vertex],OUT:[id:0,label:vertex],created:existed]
```

As to why your approach doesn't work in JanusGraph, it is hard to say given the information provided. Perhaps you should try to recreate my Gremlin Console session yourself with JanusGraph and see what happens. If it still doesn't work for you, you can then supply a fully failing example for JanusGraph experts to look at.

Comment: Not working in my case. 
Note: I am using a groovy script that loads CSV records in batches and executes the query. Is there any other way?

Comment: The problem is the edge is not selected at all, this is causing the issue

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Are you saying my exact gremlin session with my sample data didn't work with JanusGraph? If you're saying, you just pasted my query into your groovy script and it doesn't work then perhaps there is something wrong with your script in which case we might need to look at that. In the worst case you may need to provide a fully reproducible failure that can be executed in the Gremlin Console. Please start with recreating my session with JanusGraph to see if that works. The outcome of that test will tell us much.

Comment: I am using a multiprocessing groovy script which executes the CSV file in batches. The problem is the query returns the desired output when executed on the console, but the wrong result when executed using a multiprocessing groovy script. For example, consider the query g.V().has('label_A','A').outE('to').inV().has('label_B','B').hasNext() return true in console, but False through script. 'A' and 'B' in has statement are taken through CSV file. Ex g.V().has('label_A',record[0]).outE('to').inV().has('label_B',record[1]).hasNext() record[0] contains 'A' anf record[1] contains 'B'. Personal chat?

Comment: Sample code for reference 
```

importCsv(ctx, 'data.csv', 1, 1) { g, csvRecord ->


g.V().has('label_A',csvRecord[0]).as('v').V().has('label_B',csvRecord[1]).coalesce(__.inE('to').where(outV().as('v')).property('created','existed'),addE('to').from('v').property('created','newAdded'))
 g.tx().commit()
}

```

Comment: there is a problem with your groovy script - your traversal isn't executing. you need to `iterate()` your traversal - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration